# Outlook Addin - Is there any expiry time for the data saved on the server through saveAsync method of RoamingSettings?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an outlook add-in where it is required to save the data to outlook server which can be used further. I am using saveAsync method for persisting the data and use the same for the add-in. Now i am not sure if there is any expiry of the data stored on the server. I have checked the documentation also but nowhere anything is mentioned related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no expiration on your data. If you want to expire it, you'd need to do that explicitly in your code.